# Can I use "no problem" for expressing okay?

Tags: american-english

One friend of mine A and I have misunderstanding on use of "no problem"

For example, the conversation between A and me:

```
A: should we meet at 16:30 in science building?

I: Ok, that's no problem for me

A: Do agree that then? @I @B

B: agreed

I: no problem for me.

A: By “no problem” you mean agreed - or something else?
```

Am I using "no problem" in a wrong way? Is it wrong to express agreement using "no problem"?

Comment: By 'okay' in your example, you mean that 'it is possible', then the answer is yes. The person you were speaking to may not have grasped this particular usage of 'no problem.' https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/no%20problem

Comment: That is, no, you are not using it in a wrong way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your usage is grammatically correct.

**no problem**  [TFD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/No+problem)

Used to express **confirmation** of or **compliance** with a request.
Used to acknowledge an expression of gratitude.